# Reshape Array from 3*180*180 to 180*180*3 without changing the axis value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array `a` with shape `3*180*180`, and when I plot its first index like just `a[0].plot()` which will have shape `180*180`, here's the result:

[image]

Now I want to reshape it to `180*180*3` in such a way that it maintains it's axis so I just simply tried `a.reshape(180, 180, 3)`, so when I just plot `b[:, :, 0]` which will have same shape as earlier plot `180*180` I want the same plot, instead I'm getting something like this:

[image]

Can Someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what's the correct way of doing so.

Comment: `a.transpose(1,2,0)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang you just saved my day, thanks! :)